# Tool for valgrind memcheck xtree file

Tags: valgrind, memcheck

I am trying to find the correct tool for displaying the results contained in the file generated by :

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --xtree-memory=full --xml=yes --xml-file=memcheck_result.xml [prog]
```

This produces a file named `xtmemory.kcg.[pid]` which is largely unreadable ... at least to me !

Since we have kcachegrind for visualising callgrind trees and graphs, is there really no tool for the xtmemory file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

kcachegrind is the tool to use to visualise xtmemory files.

See http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.xtree